# PHP base64 encode a PDF file - Timing out

Tags: php, xml, pdf, base64

So I am using a Web Service and I am generating an XML file, I need to send across PDF files as base64 encode instead of just passing the URL.

The XML is processing around 500 requests and the way I am encoding the PDF is as follows:-

```
$filesrc = get_field('property_pdf');
$b64Doc = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filesrc)));
```

However, when I am doing this the process ends up just timing out, is there better way of encoding a PDF or am I not doing it correctly?

*Note: It processes all 500 properties in less than 5 seconds before adding the above code to the XML generation.*

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are talking about 500 x 5 seconds you should queue the jobs and run them in the background.

Comment: @jeroen - Sorry I meant without encoding the PDF it would take < 5 seconds to loop through all 500 properties and generate the XML